# Azure website with 'updatable' classic asp scripts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp-classic

A client is looking into redeveloping their classic asp website to MVC4 and hosting on Azure.
The problem is that they have a massive suite of classic asp reports that they would like to keep using. They will want to continue adding and amending the classic asp scripts more or less like they do at the moment - which is via ftp.

I know that classic asp can be enabled within Azure. My issue is how in a multi-instance environment can a classic asp developer (with no .NET or Azure knowledge) upload new scripts to Azure without having to upload the whole Azure application. Could he possible upload to blob storage and I could pull the new scripts in to local storage? If that's possible can those scripts be made web accessible?

Many Thanks,
Neil

Comment: You do have remote desktop access.  You have tools like Azure Storage Explorer/CloudXplorer where they can visually drag over files from Blob storage to the local storage of the VM.  You could even run this on a durable VM (IaaS) and run an ftp server (if they are used to that).  Also, you could automate this for them using PowerShell scripts.  The tricky part about this is deploying this in a way where if the VM is updated/rebooted your stuff would stay...move IIS to a durable drive.  All the stuff you say is definitely do-able.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fairly easy achievable, but requires a little extra work on your (the MVC/Azure dev) side. 
First is to upload all classic ASP files in a blob container. There are various free and paid tools which can help you with that. Next, you can let your classic ASP devs edit the files and upload to the blob itself.

Next comes the hard-core work from your side. You can extend the [RoleEntryPoint class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleentrypoint.aspx) and add your implementation as part of your project. In that class, you have a [Run method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleentrypoint.run.aspx), which shall never exit, thus the `while(true)` loop.
Within that infinite loop, you can decide to sleep for like 1, or 5, or 10 minutes. Next on each iteration, you can check for new versions of the ASP files in the blob and download if any.
You will have to find the appropriate place where to download the files to, because your [RoleEntryPoint implementation will live not in the IIS process that runs your website, but in a separate WaIISHost.exe process](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2010/12/02/new-full-iis-capabilities-differences-from-hosted-web-core.aspx).
There are [various methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345508/how-can-i-get-the-webrole-site-root-path-from-roleentrypoint-onstart) on [how to determine the site root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555668/how-to-programmatically-get-sites-list-and-virtual-dirs-in-iis-7).

I highly suggest this approach, rather then the one with a VM(IaaS).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the links. "easily achievable" are two of my favorite words :)