# Windows Azure RDP / FTP

Tags: azure

Using the new interface for Windows Azure, how do I enable RDP? I am using a cloud service and my site is mysite.cloudapp.net. In my publish settings, I enabled RDP. Where do I find my RDP credentials? How do I enable FTP, if possible? Here are the instructions that I followed:

https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/remote-desktop/

I see no hosted services tab in the new layout.

When I try to RDP, I receive an instant failure message that I cannot connect. I am using Windows 8 and I tried Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For RDP, assuming you've followed all the steps and the configuration is right, you need to use the management portal, click on cloud services on the left and select the service whose instance you want to RDP into, select instances in the menu at the top and then pick the instance you want to RDP into.
The bottom toolbar should include a connect option, clicking on it should download an RDP file you can open to RDP into the machine, this will prompt you for the credentials you need to provide (as provided in your project configuration).

You can actually save this RDP file and re-use it for the deployment, but it may become invalid if you re-deploy as port numbers change.

As for FTP, much has been written about it, for example [this](http://khailiangtech.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/windows-azure-how-to-enable-ftp/), but you really need to consider the note in this article, for example - files you upload to the role instance will disappear if the role needs to be recycled for whatever reason.

Comment: Thanks for the info! My site is taking an hour to upload. Is there a way to speed it up? I am only changing the web.config file.

Comment: Short answer is no, but it would be worth you taking a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362191/is-it-possible-to-edit-web-config-of-cloud-app-deployed-on-windows-azure-without - it depends what it is that you're doing, you might not actually want to use web.config for settings, for exampe, or you might want to test changes by using RDP and then push the package when you're ready.