# Update web.config to add rewrite rules for specific environments in Azure DevOps release pipeline for an Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

What is a good way to update web.config for a Azure Application Service webapp in AZDO to add rewrite rules? We use Azure DevOps to deploy a webapp that uses a web.config and we want to set URL Rewrite rules based on the environment it is. We have some default values in a web.config to be used across all environments, but just need to add some lines for the rewrite rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Update web.config to add rewrite rules for specific environments in Azure DevOps release pipeline for an Azure App Service

To rewrite or replace rules for specific environments in the `web.config`, we could use `xdt:Transform="Insert"` to add some lines for the rewrite rule based on different environments.

For the `Web.Release.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

.....
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite xdt:Transform="Insert">
      <rules>
        ......
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

For the [Azure App Service Deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops) task, there is an option **XML transformation** under **File Transforms & Variable Substitution Options**:

[image]

The XML transformation supports transforming the configuration files (*.config files) by following Web.config Transformation Syntax and is based on the environment to which the web package will be deployed.

Check this document [XML Transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Question about the transform files. The XML Transformation document you linked, are the transform files the Web.Release.config and Web.Production.config files? These transform files are supposed to be deployed to the same directory as the web.config file correct?

Comment: Also, does the the stage name in the release definition need to match the file name? So if a stage in my release pipeline is called PROD, the transform file should be called Web.PROD.config?

Comment: @AnthonyKlotz, The answer for the questions in the first comment is yes.

Comment: @AnthonyKlotz, The answer for the questions in the second comment is also yes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#configuration-transform-file-naming-conventions

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was able to use your solution to transform the web.config in the release pipeline with the task.

Answer (score 1):

For this issue , we could update the configuration of Web App by updating Web.config file directly. You could upload a new version of configuration file to wwwroot folder by FTP/WebDeply or any other ways provided by Kudu. Another easy way to edit files in wwwroot folder is using the [App Service Editor](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36467.understanding-the-azure-app-service-editor.aspx), you could use it to edit the configuration file.

You can refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42352354/what-is-the-proper-way-to-add-rewrite-rules-in-an-azure-app-service) with similar issue. Hope this helps.

Comment: We would like to change the web.config in the release pipeline by using a pipeline task. Can a deployment script setting in the Azure App Service Deploy task do this?

Comment: How about Leo's answer, is it what you want?

Comment: That looks ideal, I'll need to read more information about XML transformation to do it.

Comment: If Leo's answer is helpful to you ,you could consider to accept it as an Answer , so it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily.

Comment: Will do, I'm adding some comments to get clarification as I attempt to implement that solution

Comment: Your answer was useful, as I was able "PUT" a file up to the app service using Kudu. But I found Leo's solution to be the better way. Thank you for your input, I've marked Leo's answer as the solution.